# Group values by another fields max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have  the following Table

```
ID | Name | Salary
---+------+-------
1  |Tom   | 100
2  |Tom   | 600
3  |Max   | 300
4  |Jim   | 400
5  |Max   | 200
6  |Tom   | 600
7  |Jim   | 100
```

I try to get those IDs and names which have the max salary.

Expected Result

```
ID | Name 
---|------
2  | Tom
3  | Max
4  | Jim
```

Actual Result

```
ID | Name 
---|------
2  | Tom
6  | Tom << duplicate name
3  | Max
4  | Jim
```

The Filter is done by

```
SELECT e1.ID, e1.Name
FROM Employee e1
WHERE e1.Salary = 
(
  SELECT MAX(e2.Salary) 
  FROM Employee e2
  WHERE e1.Name = e2.Name
);
```

Unfortunately duplicates appear twice if the max salary appears twice - how do I have to change the subselect to suppress duplicate names

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9980/3/0

Comment: Well, which Tom with a Salary of 600 do you want?

Comment: @HoneyBadger does not matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: @Larnu that can't be solved with a Group By

Comment: Have a look at the answer in the link. It's relevant; and there are 1,000's of answer out there on how to only return the first value of a set of duplicate results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would normally be done using `row_number()`:

```
select . ..
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```